# Как соединяют витую пару при прокладке кабеля на большие расстояния?

Tags: сеть, ethernet, передача-данных

Читал про Ethernet 1000BASE-T. Там написано, что максимальная длина сегмента 100 метров. Правильно ли я понимаю, что длина отрезка кабеля должна быть максимум 100 метров? И как соединяют эти отрезки кабеля?

Comment: Вам для практических применений? Если да, то обрисуйте ситуацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хороший кабель, медь 0.52, может соединять отрезки кабеля до 150 метров. 100 метров - это гарантированная длинна для стандарта.

Ограничение связанно с потерей напряжения в кабеле.

Между отрезками ставятся коммутаторы, от которых разводятся провода по компьютерам.

Также удлинить можно повторителем. Между повторителями промежуток может быть больше так как там встроен усилитель. Пример MIKROTIK GPER может работать на 210 метров.

На расстояния больше 100 метров оптика выходит дешевле.

Comment: Ограничение связано не с потерей напряжения, а со временем распространения сигнала.

Comment: @gbg тогда 10 мегабит било б на километр)

Comment: Наоборот, именно для того, чтобы  CSMA/CD верно работало на 10мегабитах, ввели это самое ограничение в 100 метров. Все дальнейшие стандарты это ограничение унаследовали.

Comment: @gbg я про питание говорил потому, что оно необходимо репитеру. Хоть по PoE, хоть через адаптер

Comment: @gbg может напишите правильный ответ?

Comment: @gbg на разделяемой среде - да. В случае же, если домен коллизий вырожден (то есть в 2020 году — всегда*), зависит только от строгости соответствия железа стандарту и обычно работает дальше, чем 100 метров, но короче, чем 200.

Answer (score 2):

1 вариант - Оптоволокно и медиаконверторы. Абонентские оптоволоконные кабели стоят не дорого. В итоге может выйти дешевле, чем прокладка UTP. Либо прокинуть магистральное оптоволокно и специалисты разошьют его в абонентских кроссах за небольшую плату.

2 вариант - Репитер. Если рядом с местом соединения есть электрическая розетка, то можно воткнуть оба кабеля в репитер и будет вам счастье. Если розетки нет, то тогда придётся докупить ещё PoE-инжектор (важно, чтобы репитер поддерживал PoE), но тогда об 1 Gb/s придётся забыть, максимум 100. Если всё же нужна гигабитка, то можно использовать PoE-свитч, но тогда придётся подводить два кабеля с одного конца, либо дополнительный кабель питания.

3 вариант - Wi-Fi антенны. На улице между точками в прямой видимости можно разместить две антенны (напр. Microtik), но нужно точное наведение (юстировка) антенн друг на друга. Очень выгодный вариант, если видимость прямая и очень большое расстояние (до 10 км)

Comment: PoE работает и на гигабите.

Comment: @gbg пасивное работает

Comment: Точное)) юстировку всегда на глаз) sxt и loco плюс-минус 10° попадают без проблем